# Cannot start Oracle XE 11gR2 Net Listener and Database on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, database, oracle, oracle-11g

I have been following the setup step on [this article](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html) for installing Oracle XE 11g R2 on Ubuntu 13.04. The environment variables PATH, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, NLS_LANG ORACLE_BASE have all been set up correctly.

```
simongao:~ 06:16:38$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/simongao/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin
simongao:~ 06:18:36$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
simongao:~ 06:23:29$ echo $ORACLE_SID
XE
simongao:~ 06:23:35$ echo $ORACLE_BASE
/u01/app/oracle
simongao:~ 06:23:37$ sudo echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib
simongao:~ 06:23:48$ echo $NLS_LANG
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh
```

However, when I try to startup the service, I receive the following error information.

```
simongao:~ 06:18:40$ sudo service oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem on Ubuntu 13 running in virtual box.

Try to first create a system user called oracle

That solved the problem stated above for me but I was not able to run "sqlplus sys as sysdba." Even so, I was then able to connect to remote host using "sqlplus tns-user/password@remote-address"